# @ mentions on Facebook using Facebook Connect API

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to do @ mentions on Facebook using either facebook.stream.publish or facebook.users.setStatus.

You are able to do this on Facebook and I know its possible to do using 3rd party APIs as a "Twitter Sync" app currently supports it.

So far I have tried using: `@[fb_id]`, `@:fb_id`, `@[fb_id:fb_name]`, `@:[fb_id:fb_name]` and `@:[fb_id]` in the stream message.

I know Facebook.com uses `@[fb_id:fb_name]` on the site.
I also know Facebook's Dashboard API uses `@:fb_id`
I am also willing to emulate this functionality on my end if someone knows how to insert an url into the user's status or stream with custom link text or some method of inserting  FBML into the stream (`<fb:name>`)

Note: 
fb_id = Facebook User ID
fb_name = Facebook User Name
example: @[552192373:Jason Boehm]

I am currently using Facebook's Offical PHP API Client.